# Pivot Table Report Filter using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to automate a particular Pivot table filtering using VBA. I am not sure how to add "Report Filter" (please see attached screen shot) using VBA.

To automate the process, I got the code for adding rows , columns and values , but can't seem to find the code for report filter.

Can you please help me out with the code for this.

[image: Filter]

[image: Report Filter]

Comment: What code have you tried and what was the problem with it?

Comment: best way to check how to do anything - record a macro and you will see

Comment: @braX I need a code for pivot table to add Report Filter. Eg. We can add pivot tables manually and apply/insert 4 basic properties namely filters, Columns , Rows and summation value(See attached image). To automate the process, I got the code for adding rows , columns and summation values , but can't seem to find the code for report filter. Can please help with that?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @avb for the suggestion . Recording the macro helped. The code for adding pivot report filter is this.

```
    Sub pivotReportFilter(ptUse As PivotTable, fName As String)

     With ptUse.PivotFields(fName)
      .Orientation = xlPageField
      .Position = 1
     End With

   End Sub
```